# In Ubuntu 12.10 how to enable /proc/net/ip_conntrack?

Tags: 12.10, networking

I've tried `sudo modprobe ip_conntrack` to no avail.

I can't find anything about enabling this.  Does anyone know how?

Comment: I've upvoted the question and downvoted the March 12 answer.  I've seen this issue as well.  It appears that nf_conntrack has replaced ip_conntrack by 3.5 version kernels (if not earlier).  Seems to be associated with the netf or netfilter modules.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`/proc/net/ip_conntrack` is deprecated. You must install the package `apt-get install conntrack`, and then you can run `conntrack -L` and see the result

Answer (score 0):

When I can not find something which works on one kernel and on another same thing does not exist, I use this two universal commands (here adapted for finding `conntrack`):

`sudo find /proc/ -name '*conntrack*'`

or

`sudo sysctl -a | grep conntrack`

From first `find` command I learned that in my newest *Debian testing with kernel (4.8.0-1-amd64)*, I can get data about *all net connections* similar to old `/proc/net/ip_conntrack`, by running this command:

`sudo cat /proc/*/net/ip_conntrack | sort -u`