# How do I send personalized notify-send about custom events?

Tags: bash, notify-send

```
watch netstat -n -A inet             + notify-send "Attention new  connection"
```

or

```
watch  cat /proc/net/ip_conntrack    + notify-send "Attention new  connection"
```

or

```
watch ss -n                          + notify-send "Attention new  connection"
```

Do you have any idea how to connect this halves and thank you.

Comment: Wait a minute... you want a notification each time a socket is opened?

Comment: Which desktop manager are you using? as with some you can set a notification anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a short bash script, like:

```
#!/bin/sh
while [ 1 ]
do
  if [ "PARAMETER" = "SOMETHING" ]; then
     notify-send "Attention" "There is a new connection."
  else
     echo "Nothing Found"
  fi
  sleep 5
done
```

Basically, this would listen for a `PARAMETER` *(How, I don't know...)*, and when it equals `SOMETHING`, then it will send a notification. If the `PARAMETER` is not equal to `SOMETHING`, it will print `Nothing Found` *(This is not necessary, it just shows that it is working)*, wait for 5 seconds, and start again.

The problem is getting it find when it has connected... None of these...

- `netstat -n -A inet`
- `cat /proc/net/ip_conntrack` - apparently deprecated anyway, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/279490/178596)
- `ss -n`

...seem to produce the parameters required...

---

<sub>Any corrections welcome, especially with the bash script</sub>